# Surface area of the upper part of the elliptic paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here is given the question:

Find the surface area of the upper part of the elliptic paraboloid $z = 16 - x^2 - y^2.$

I have solved it and my answer is $\frac{\pi}{6}(65\sqrt{65} - 1)$, but I am not sure whether the solution is right or no. Therefore, I would be glad if someone could give it a try and we will compare answers.

Comment: I got the same thing. Your answer is correct.

Comment: thank you very much!